# How to copy new items without duplicates to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 2 tabs:

DailyInv: is imported from an external program as an Xls and ran through a simple script to cut out the fat.

ProductMasterList: is a library of all the items we have.

I would like to create a script that checks 'DailyInv' for any new items in column A (Product#) that are not on 'ProductMasterList', and then copy Column A & B for the new items to the next available row on 'ProductMasterList'.

I use a filter view on 'ProductMasterList' to sort through the items. The filter seems to break the script below and it'll start to add duplicates at the very bottom of the sheet.

quite a few of the numbers I use start with 00 as well. Is there a way to make sure it doesn't drop the 0's?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DH7FuhtlxJPpRUbBr1HETm0x2lMqXqwaBgVzBJ9hzvk/edit#gid=0

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: We need to know how DailyInv is loaded

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

```
function checkDailyInv() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("DailyInv");
  const list = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 2).getValues();//assume one header row
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName("ProductMasterList");
  const vs = msh.getRange(2, 1, msh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();//assume one header row
  const arr = [];
  list.forEach(r => {
    if (!~vs.indexOf(r[0])) {
      arr.push(r);
    }
  });
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  }
}
```